# Animate just bottom border to width of 0 upon button disabled

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise (
        resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    );
}
async function disableButton() {
document.getElementById("actionButtons").disabled = true;
await sleep(5000);
document.getElementById("actionButtons").disabled = false;
}
document.getElementById("actionButtons").addEventListener("click", function() { disableButton(); })
```

```css
#actionButtons {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
#actionButtons:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: black;
}
#actionButtons:disabled:after{
  height: 4px;
  transform-origin: bottom; 
  animation: cooldown 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes cooldown{
  from{
    width: 100%;
  }
  to {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="actionButtons"></button>
```

This snippet is now what I've found as a solution to what I was looking for. Thank you for all the help!
I'm attempting to create a button with a cooldown.
I have javascript setup to disable then enable the button. I want a thicker full width bottom border upon being disabled, and that border to animate to a width of 0, upon which the but is reenabled.
My issue is with the CSS, getting a bottom border created upon disabled that I can then animate. Any animations I use effect the entire button, how can I just access the bottom border? Also, I want it to only animate to 0, once enabled I dont want the animation going back to full width. This is the CSS code I have:

```
.actionButtons {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.actionButtons:disabled {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    bottom: -6px;
    width: 119px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black; 
    animation: cooldown 10s linear;
}
@keyframes cooldown {
    0% { width: 100%; }
    100% { width: 0; }
}
```

Any ideas for how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi There. try creating a minimal reproducible demo using the snippet creator in stackoverflow

Comment: Create bottom border in pseudo class and animate it scaleY. Animation on transforms consumes less resources.

Comment: @nisanthReddy I've edited my post to include a code snippet.

Comment: @robert How so? I've tried doing it that way, but then how do I get it to work only when it's disabled, as isn't the psuedo class applied normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as i said in comment you can use pseudo element to create border and then animate scaleY() of it. In that way you have well performed fluent animation of height.

if you will animate height in px then you will get quantized value to whole one. (tested in chrome)

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise (
        resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    );
}
async function disableButton() {
document.getElementById("actionButtons").disabled = true;
await sleep(5000);
document.getElementById("actionButtons").disabled = false;
}
document.getElementById("actionButtons").addEventListener("click", function() { disableButton(); })
```

```css
#actionButtons {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#actionButtons:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}

#actionButtons:disabled {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    bottom: -6px;
    width: 119px;
    animation: cooldown 5s linear forwards;
}

#actionButtons:disabled:after{
  height: 5px;
  transform-origin: bottom; 
  animation: scale-down 4s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes scale-down{
  from{
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes cooldown {
    0% { width: 100%; }
    100% { width: 0; }
}
```

```html
<button id="actionButtons"></button>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I'm not sure where you got height from, as I specified width originally, but nonetheless was able to easily change it to what I'm looking for - I think I got stuck not doing it on disabled:after, and then using the transform origin, and linear forwards as that solved it too! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you were trying to achieve but you can use `transition` css-property to auto animate css changes.

In your case, you can add,

```
transition: border 1s ease;
```

to animate your border.

I have reduced the sleep to `1s` and increased the border width to `10px` just for presentational purposes.

Is this what you wanted to achieve ?

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  );
}
async function disableButton() {
  document.getElementById("actionButtons").disabled = true;
  await sleep(1000);
  document.getElementById("actionButtons").disabled = false;
}
document.getElementById("actionButtons").addEventListener("click", function() {
  disableButton();
})
```

```css
#actionButtons {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: border 1s ease;
}

#actionButtons:disabled {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  bottom: -6px;
  width: 119px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button id="actionButtons"></button>
```

Comment: Sorry, was just editing my snippet to show better: I'm trying to get the larger bottom border to go from full width, to 0% and then disappear(not animating back to full width). I've tried doing the transition of width but it causes the whole button to change, not just the larger bottom border